No matching distribution found for types-pkg-resources
During a Python pre-commit run with the following steps:
...

  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v1.4.1
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        additional_dependencies: [types-all]
...

The following error is presented:
Run poetry run pre-commit run --all-files
...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/home/runner/.cache/pre-commit/repot9s2e7uv/py_env-python3.9/bin/python', '-mpip', 'install', '.', 'types-all')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout:
...
stderr:
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement types-pkg-resources (from types-all) (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for types-pkg-resources

This is during a GitHub action that has been working regularly until now.

'types-all' is now deprecated, as per the repository.
'types-pkg-resources' is a dependency 'types-all', and the release has been deleted.
As such, types-all will no longer work. The next best thing will be to install the required types-* packages manually.
